# Android NetworkOnMainThreadException seems unsolvable

Tags: java, android

Working on this app, which communicated with a webserver.

I'am using okHttp for sending http requests and getting responses.

And for some reason I'll get NetworkOnMainThreadException when the request is taking to long.

All the solutions I found just wont work out.

Here is the code which works until the receiving data is taking to long.

**HttpGetRunnable.java**

```
public class HttpGetRunnable implements Runnable {

  private Request request;
  private Response response;

  public HttpGetRunnable(String route) {
    String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8080" + route;
    request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    try{
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
  }

  public Response getResponse() {
    return response;
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
try {
    HttpGetRunnable httpGet = new HttpGetRunnable("/timesheet/" + user.getId());
    Thread thread = new Thread(httpGet);

    thread.start();
    thread.join();

    Response response = httpGet.getResponse();
    String jsonString = response.body().string();   
    // ^ throw exception on this line when taking to long
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(System.out);
}
```

**Error**

```
04-16 23:06:53.042 31145-31145/com.example.jim.app I/System.out: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
.. (no caused at)
```

What I tried so far:

1. using Callable (same way as Runnable, returning Response)
2. using Callable returning response body String
3. Executing runnable in ExecutorService single pool
4. Submitting callable in ExecutorService single pool then future.get
5. Using okHttp deferred @Override methods onFailed onResponse

I just can't figure it out..
What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

**P.S**

using this version `com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0`

Comment: What version of okhttp are you using? I remember an issue report about this...

Comment: using com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0. Could it be? That will explain a lot  than

Comment: You didn't try an AsyncTask?

Comment: @cricket_007 yes tried that one but couldn't return the response from it Override onResponse

Comment: Better still just use okHttp's Asynchronous request mechanism - https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/AsynchronousGet.java

Comment: You could've made a post about that instead, but there are many duplicates about how to return a variable in an AsyncTask

Comment: you should be fine on 3.2.0, check this question for the other issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33266886/networkonmainthread-rxjava-retrofit-lollipop

Comment: Thanks for thinking with me here! Already tried the async but couldn't figure out how to retrieve and use the response. But with all the help here I am sure figure something out!

Comment: For wat downvotes? Is my question format wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong here?

You are blocking the main application thread, via `join()`. Get rid of that.

For example, [here is a sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Internet/OkHttp3) that uses OkHttp3 to request the latest Stack Overflow [[image]android](/questions/tagged/android) questions. I have a dedicated `LoadThread` that handles the HTTP I/O:

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2013-2016 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    https://commonsware.com/Android
 */

package com.commonsware.android.okhttp;

import android.util.Log;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import de.greenrobot.event.EventBus;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

class LoadThread extends Thread {
  static final String SO_URL=
      "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/questions?"
          + "order=desc&sort=creation&site=stackoverflow&tagged=android";

  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
      OkHttpClient client=new OkHttpClient();
      Request request=new Request.Builder().url(SO_URL).build();
      Response response=client.newCall(request).execute();

      if (response.isSuccessful()) {
        Reader in=response.body().charStream();
        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(in);
        SOQuestions questions=
            new Gson().fromJson(reader, SOQuestions.class);

        reader.close();

        EventBus.getDefault().post(new QuestionsLoadedEvent(questions));
      }
      else {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), response.toString());
      }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Exception parsing JSON", e);
    }
  }
}
```

But I just start that thread in `onCreate()` of a fragment. I do not then try to block the main application thread via `join()`. Instead, I use greenrobot's EventBus to find out when the data is loaded, and then use it.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out here. When I remove the join() it still get's the same error if to long, els response is empty. I'am going to try this out right now!!

Comment: @JimVercoelen: Well, bear in mind that you cannot use the `Response` until the work is completed. The OkHttp site also has [a sample of using `Callback`](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#asynchronous-get). My guess is that you are trying to return the result of the HTTP I/O from the method containing your `thread.join()` call. That will not work, unless that method itself is called on a background thread.

Comment: Yes that's why I used join(), so the response is there but this doesn't seems the correct way. Also tried that callback example but couldn't manage to return the response in method onResponse

Comment: @JimVercoelen: The pattern is not to *return* something from the background thread, but to *call* something from the background thread. That's one of the reasons I like greenrobot's EventBus: you can post the event from a background thread and have it delivered to your activity/fragment/whatever on the main application thread.

Comment: thanks for helping me out here! Still fresh with threads enco. Ill try to get this done posting after retrieving the data to the activity/fragment

Comment: @ComonsWars The greenrobot solved my problem combined with async method. Thanks